# If it is feed when one gives food to a person, what is it when water is given?

Tags: single-word-requests

When a person, say a guest, comes into a house, the host might think "I will feed my guests." But what if the guests need water, would the host say "I will water my guests" -- Because that sounds a bit odd (since water is generally used for plants). Which leads me to my question, is there a word for giving water to a person?

Comment: "you can lead a horse to water, but you can't make it drink" -saying.

Comment: Even more confusing: if when you give your guests food, you feed them, what happens when you give them wood?

Comment: You’ve treed them.